# Weird content in nginx ingress controller log

Tags: kubernetes, security, logging, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

Hi I was investigating one issue with application that is using nginx ingress controller and found this line

```
10.0.YY.XXX - - [05/Dec/2023:13:11:10 +0000] "openssl s_client -connect localapp.localdomain.com:443 | grep -i cn" 400 150 "-" "-" 0 0.143 [] [] - - - - 978e7033d12d02cd177448732a8c5c17
```

So first its our VPN ip (I anonymized that) and later something I dont understand
`openssl s_client -connect localapp.localdomain.com:443 | grep -i cn`.
Looks like pretty normall command but when executed locally not in logs in here.

I tried generate such logs but doesn't look like possible.
So I got into the pod
`kubctl exec -it ingress-controller-pod-xxx -- sh`
and executed the command. Nothing appeared in the logs which is pretty obvious based on how kubernetes is launching processes and redirecting stdout/stderr.

My question is what this log entry means why potentially appeared ?